# Python -> pyautogui and special characters for DOSBox 0.74

Tags: python, pyautogui, dosbox

I transfer data from an Excel file to DOSBox with python.
Letters ä,ö;ü,ß are not written in Dosbox. With my own physical keyboard I can write these letters.

1. Question: Does anyone know how I can do this with python?

2nd question: Then I tried to find a solution with ALT+... unfortunately that doesn't work either.

```
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')   #altgr doesn't work too
pyautogui.press('1')
pyautogui.press('4')
pyautogui.press('8')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

3. Down arrow doesn't work either.

```
`pyautogui.press('down')`
```

Anyone have an idea or is this not possible?

Thank you!

I asked ChatGPT, I'm suggested to try it via a subprocess, but that doesn't work because a new console opens for each command espite -noconsole

Comment: Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details. For example, what's your OS? Did you configure [the keyboard layout](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/KEYB)? Then what's the configured layout?